# Wix, where can I find WixUI_InstallDir.wxs and InstallDirDlg.wxs

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I've just been assigned a task of working (learning) WIX.  To better understand the dialog handling and stuff, I found many references of "just get..." and then WixUI_InstallDir.wxs and InstallDirDlg.wxs (and obviously the others out there).

I've searched all over (several hours) and have YET to actually find the raw .WXS files these other links have directed me to.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For version 3.5, the source code is at http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=wix35

Comment: This link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 12):

In case you are looking where wxs files are in the source tree, for 3.6 they are here:

```
src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib
```

And as AntonyW already pointed out the source can be downloaded from codeplex. This is the link for version 3.6:
http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=wix36

The lastest version is available through this direct link:
http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/InstallDirDlg.wxs

Answer (score 1):

The files can be found in the folder where Wix Toolset is installed.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\wixui
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's the latest source files. Thanks for the help.

http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3.7.1015.0/wix37-sources.zip